# How to make table result not to show up in two rows in jupyter notebook when calling show method of pysaprk dataframe

Tags: pyspark, jupyter-notebook

When I call `foo.show()`,if the `foo` dataframe contains too many columns, the result won't be printed in a single row in jupyter notebook.Instead it will be splitted into two rows,and not easy to read for human.How can I solve this problem?

[image: table not showing in one row]

Comment: that's just how it works. Just use a widder screen.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there is no problem.

Answer (score 0):

A solution can be to display the dataframe in a different view, using the attributes of [pyspark.sql.DataFrame.show](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.0/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.show.html):

```
foo.show(vertical=True, truncate=False)
```

Otherwise, if you have a small dataframe, you can use a workaround and convert it to Pandas:

```
foo.toPandas()
```